# Excel publish multiple sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to publish multiple sheets in the excel using VBA. I need to publish sheet 2 and 3.

Below is the code.

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    .WebOptions.AllowPNG = False
        With .PublishObjects(2)
            Range("A1").Activate
            .Filename = "D:\Reports\09192014\MNM.html"
            .Publish (True)
        End With
End With
```

In the `PublishObjects(2)` I am changing the number from 2 to 3 manually like below.

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    .WebOptions.AllowPNG = False
        With .PublishObjects(3)
            Range("A1").Activate
            .Filename = "D:\Reports\09192014\Coal.html"
            .Publish (True)
        End With
 End With
```

Still though, in the HTML report `coal.html` I am getting `MNM.html` data and that too has half of the data.
How can I iterate the sheets and publish objects?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be adding it first like this?:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceSheet, _
        "D:\Reports\09192014\MNM.html", "Sheet1", , _
        xlHtmlStatic, , "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False '~~> True updates HTML when workbook is saved
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceSheet, _
        "D:\Reports\09192014\Coal.html", "Sheet2", , _
        xlHtmlStatic, , "")
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False
    End With
```

After adding it, that is the time you can access it using `PublishObjects Collection` via index number.
Index will be based on the sequence the `Object` was created.

Comment: When it try to use the same code application is displaying an error message "Object required" Replaced Sheet1 with MNM Report(Sheet I want to publish) and even tried with Sheet 1 but still getting an error message.

Comment: @user3670700 **Sheet1** should be replaced by the name of the sheet. Also try recording a macro while doing the publishing manually to get the right entries on the arguments.

Comment: This is working but we need to add one more line before publish line. With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceSheet, _
        "D:\Reports\09192014\MNM.html", "Sheet1", , _
        xlHtmlStatic, , "") Range("A1").activate
        .Publish (True)
        .AutoRepublish = False '~~> True updates HTML when workbook is saved
    End With